# Need VBA to unprotect range of form control checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have form control checkboxes in a specified range on a worksheet named "PayAdj" (cells `c23:c1000`).  I need to unprotect them so that when the worksheet is locked, users can still "check" and "uncheck" the checkboxes.

There are too many to manually unprotect by right clicking  "Form Controls" selecting the "Protection" tab, then unselecting the "Locked" box. I have searched far and wide for a solution, and attempted to modify similar VBA code but failed.

Now completely frustrated.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to include the VBA code you tried.

Comment: Go to the Home tab, Find & Select and and choose Select Objects or the Selection Pane. With Select Objects Ctrl-A should, I believe, select them all then you could right-click to unlock them all. Or drag around an area.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Sub UnlockCBs()
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        cb.Locked = False
    Next cb
End Sub